# How to fix a [flat] tire

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There is a tag [flat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flat) with 170 questions that seems to fall flat of what it's supposed to be:

> A flat style means a leveled, even, bi-dimensional style of UI components. The UI will result in something which doesn't have a 3D look (i.e. without glosses or reflections and without shadows).

Still most of the questions are about something completely different. There are some about flat arrays, some about flat text files, flat database designs... Only a few are about actual flat UI styles.

Furthermore I don't think UI design styles are on-topic on Stack Overflow. If you want to discuss flat design in a specific environment there are more specific tags for Android, Windows, iOS, and other platforms that can be used.

Considering the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does describe something about the questions, but it is not unambiguous. Flat files, flat database designs, flat UI designs...

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

In my eyes - no. Design choices are not on-topic, whereas how to use some flat UI library might be.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, it doesn't. Flat UI design isn't the main point of the question. Flat database designs or flat files might be, but the tag isn't about those.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As can be seen from the questions it doesn't. Flat is just flat and requires another word to specify what is flat.

Therefore I recommend burninating [flat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flat). If the questions that aren't related to flat UI design were edited and the tag removed there would be very few questions left anyway.